# pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'

Tags: python, mongodb

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://test:*****@cluster0.jyuin.mongodb.net/baka?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

db = cluster['baka']
collection = db['test']

post = {'id_': 0, 'name':'nksama'}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

there is nothing wrong this code right ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 72, in _resolve_uri                                                                
    results = resolver.query('_mongodb._tcp.' + self.__fqdn, 'SRV',                                                                                                                 
TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "D:\python codes\db\test\dbb.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                                        
    cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://nksama:nksama@cluster0.jyuin.mongodb.net/baka?retryWrites=true&w=majority')                                                                
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 639, in __init__                                                                   
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(                                                                                                                                                     
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 500, in parse_uri                                                                    
    nodes = dns_resolver.get_hosts()                                                                                                                                                
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 102, in get_hosts                                                                  
    _, nodes = self._get_srv_response_and_hosts(True)                                                                                                                               
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 83, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts                                                 
    results = self._resolve_uri(encapsulate_errors)                                                                                                                                 
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 79, in _resolve_uri                                                                
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))                                                                                                                                              
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'
```

Comment: What are the versions of Python, PyMongo and MongoDB you are working with?

Comment: @prasad_ python version is 3.9.5 pymongo version is latest

Comment: The error may be related to the url with "mongodb+srv" format. Try installing this to resolve: `python -m pip install pymongo[srv]`

Answer (score 0):

In Most cases, this occurs because of outdated dnspython lib. I solved my issue just by re-installing / updating dnspython

```
pip3 install dnspython
```

Comment: I ran into issues with SRV lookups using `dnspython==2.1.0`, but had more success with `dnspython==2.0.0`

Comment: never to use dnspython3 it just use the old dnspython causing the error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall pymongo and install once again

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo[srv]
```

Install dnspython

```
pip install dnspython3
```

This should work